# jquery syntax for making positive variable integer negative

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to js and a bit stuck (with something that is probably very ease to fix)

I have worked out the height of a div, but I want the variable to be a negative value (so i can centre something horizontally)

Here is the *wrong* jquery

```
var modal_height = $('#modal div').outerHeight()/2;
$('#modal div').css('marginTop','-'+modal_height);
```

Basically as you can see im trying to make the final marginTop value a negative one (i.e. adding a minus sign before the variable)

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: you should accept @slaks's answer since you (probably) liked it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the unary minus operator: `-modal_height`.
This operator returns a negative number.
(If the original number is already negative, it will return a positive number instead)